# Invalid character '' in input string at LitJson.Lexer.NextToken ()

Tags: unity, c#, android, json

Here's my script:

```
 IEnumerator Refresh_()
{
    Debug.LogWarning("TODO: Loading Popup on.");

    rh.eLanguage language = tzGlobal.Instance.OPTION.language;

    string json = StreetUtility.LoadJsonFromStreamingAssets("notice.json");
    if (json != null)
    {
        // Separate only the necessary parts.
        LitJson.JsonData data = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject(json);
        json = data[language.ToString()].ToJson();

        notice = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<string[]>(json);
    }

    string path = string.Format("{0}/{1}/language", rh.Const.LOCALIZATION_PATH, language);
    json = StreetUtility.LoadJsonFromResources(path);
    if (json != null)
    {
        // json load.
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

        // dictionary copy.
        dic_localization_text = new Dictionary<eTextKey, string>();
        eTextKey e;
        for (int i = 0; i < dic.Count; i++)
        {
            e = (eTextKey)i;
            dic_localization_text[e] = dic[e.ToString()];
        }

        // Run registered localize function.
        for (int i = 0; i < list_localize_method.Count; i++)
        {
            complete = false;
            list_localize_method[i].Invoke();
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => complete);
        }
    }

    Debug.LogWarning("TODO: Loading Popup off.");
}
```

Now what is happening here is that it loads the `notice.json` file but then as the execution goes this error will pop out

> Failed to Load.
>                                             LitJson.JsonException: Invalid character '﻿' in input string
>                                               at LitJson.Lexer.NextToken () [0x00000] in :0 
>                                               at LitJson.JsonReader.ReadToken () [0x00000] in :0 
>                                               at LitJson.JsonReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
>                                               at LitJson.JsonMapper.ReadValue (LitJson.WrapperFactory factory, LitJson.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                               at LitJson.JsonMapper.ToWrapper (LitJson.WrapperFactory factory, System.String json) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                               at LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject (System.String json) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                               at StreetUtility.LoadJsonFromStreamingAssets (System.String path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                             notice.json

Here's my code of my `LoadJsonFromStreamingAssets()` that i uses of calling my `notice.json` :

```
public static string LoadJsonFromStreamingAssets(string path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder)
{
    string json = null;
    try
    {
        //Android Platform
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string full_path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
        if (full_path.Contains("://") || full_path.Contains(":///"))
        {
            WWW www = new WWW(full_path);
            while (!www.isDone) { }
            json = www.text;
        }
        else
        {
            json = File.ReadAllText(full_path);
        }
        Debug.Log("Loaded File : " + json);
        JsonData itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(json);

#elif UNITY_IOS //IOS Platform

#elif UNITY_STANDALONE //PC Platform
        string full_path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Application.streamingAssetsPath, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(full_path);
        json = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        reader.Close();

        Debug.Log(json);
#endif
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarningFormat("Failed to Load.\n{0}\n{1}", e, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
    }
    return json;
}
```

And here is my json file

```
{

"EN": [
"Cancel is available with Cancel button.",
"If you succeed in a lottery, you can receive additional rewards.",
"Round 2 and 3 are shorter than you think.",
"Please check the homepage in Confirm Game Method and Change Member Information."
],
"KR": [
"Cancel 버튼으로 배팅 취소가 가능합니다.",
"로또에 성공하면 추가적인 보상을 받을 수 있습니다.",
"라운드 2와 3은 생각보다 시간이 짧습니다.",
"게임 방법 확인 및 회원정보 변경은 홈페이지에서 확인해주세요."
],
"CN": [
"[中文] Cancel is available with Cancel button.",
"[中文] If you succeed in a lottery, you can receive additional rewards.",
"[中文] Round 2 and 3 are shorter than you think.",
"[中文] Please check the homepage in Confirm Game Method and Change Member Information."
],
"HK": [
"[广东话] Cancel is available with Cancel button.",
"[广东话] If you succeed in a lottery, you can receive additional rewards.",
"[广东话] Round 2 and 3 are shorter than you think.",
"[广东话] Please check the homepage in Confirm Game Method and Change Member Information."
]
}
```

And i uses [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/) for verifying my json file and yes it is valid. I don't know why it is happening . Could someone point out what's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do here is that in your

```
if (full_path.Contains("://") || full_path.Contains(":///"))
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(full_path);
        while (!www.isDone) { }
        json = www.text;
    }
    else
    {
        json = File.ReadAllText(full_path);
    }
    Debug.Log("Loaded File : " + json);
    JsonData itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(json);
```

You must comment out this `JsonData itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(json);` This will lead you to another error i'm very sure of it . Just trim out your json file

```
json = www.text.Trim();
```

That's it. That is why you have this error

> Invalid character '' in input string at LitJson.Lexer.NextToken ()

Though you have the correct JSON format still it won't work unless you trim it.

Any by the way. Hello Copy Cat. :)

Comment: If only i could treat you somewhere sir . Thank you very very much

Comment: glad could help . Just a simple Check on my answer is good