# How do I fix "Invalid character '' in input string at LitJson.Lexer.NextToken ()" when trying to use JSON from URL?

Tags: unity, c#

When trying to use a Json file served by a url I am getting the error

```
JsonException: Invalid character '' in input string
```

it happens when I use this method:

```
IEnumerator GetText()
{
   UnityWebRequest webjson = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://awebsite.com/Art_.json");

    yield return webjson.SendWebRequest();

    if (webjson.isNetworkError || webjson.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(webjson.error);
    }
    else
    {
        // The following line is giving me the error:
        // ItemDatabase_+<GetText>d__3.MoveNext () (at Assets/Version2.0/Scripts/ItemDatabase_.cs:38)
        itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(webjson.downloadHandler.text);

        Debug.Log(itemData);

        ConstructItemDatabase();

    }
}
```

I have tried to use `Trim()`

```
itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(webjson.downloadHandler.text.Trim());
```

But still have the same result.

I have tried what is suggested in [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154791/invalid-character-in-input-string-at-litjson-lexer-nexttoken) question/answer, but it seems to not fix the issue I have.

Comment: Can you work out what character it's failing on? What's the smallest URL-encoded JSON object you can provide that reproduces this issue?

Comment: @DMGregory - Would this require me to use another json file? Happy to do any tests, but may just need a little guidance

Comment: I tried with another Json file and I get no error, but I check the validitiy of the original json file with JSONLint and it is valid... and the original works when being served locally.

Comment: Start taking things out of that JSON file until you have the smallest subset that still causes the error, and post that minimal example.

Comment: Bumping this as I have not found the solution

Comment: We'll have a hard time solving it without that minimal complete verifiable example you were asked to include.

Comment: In the end I thank everyone for their help and I was able to get this working by hosting the json file not from a personal server but from hosting the json here: http://myjson.com/
I am not sure why hosting on my server was causing this error as it was printing in the console just the same as the file that works. I will investigate why this is the case and update.

Comment: The server sends some metadata about the encoding of the file when it's fetched. If that metadata is wrong, then your program might have been trying to read the file with the wrong. character set or something like that. If it's mostly ASCII you might not see a visible difference — the misinterpreted character might be hiding in the whitespace or end of line / end of file markers. Or it could be that, as a dedicated JSON host, that website automatically does some sanitation for you and cleaned up the bad character on upload.